# Гистограмма вывод целых чисел

Tags: android

Использую библиотеку  `compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.2'`

Как сделать чтоб данные выводились целочисленно без запятой.

```
   // in this example, a LineChart is initialized from xml
    BarChart chart = (BarChart) view.findViewById(R.id.chart);

    List<BarEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
    entries.add(new BarEntry(0, 30));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(1, 80));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(2, 60));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(3, 50));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(4, 70));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(5, 60));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(6, 60));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(7, 60));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(8, 60));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(9, 60));

    BarDataSet set = new BarDataSet(entries, "BarDataSet");
    set.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FF8000"));
    chart.setDrawValueAboveBar(true);


    BarData data = new BarData(set);

    data.setBarWidth(0.8f); // set custom bar width
    chart.setData(data);
    chart.setFitBars(true); // make the x-axis fit exactly all bars
    chart.invalidate(); // refresh


    String[] values = new String[] {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"};

    XAxis xAxis = chart.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setValueFormatter(new MyXAxisValueFormatter(values));

    xAxis.setGranularity(1);
    xAxis.setGranularityEnabled(true);
    xAxis.setLabelCount(10);
    chart.getXAxis().setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);


    return view;
}

public static Fragment_infografika_lvl newInstance() {
    return new Fragment_infografika_lvl();
}

public class MyXAxisValueFormatter implements IAxisValueFormatter {

    private String[] mValues;

    public MyXAxisValueFormatter(String[] values) {
        this.mValues = values;
    }

    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
        // "value" represents the position of the label on the axis (x or y)
        return mValues[(int) value];
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Из документации](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/The-ValueFormatter-interface)

```
public class MyValueFormatter implements IValueFormatter {

    private DecimalFormat mFormat;

    public MyValueFormatter() {
        mFormat = new DecimalFormat("###,###,##0.0"); // use one decimal
    }

    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, Entry entry, int dataSetIndex, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {
        // write your logic here
        return mFormat.format(value) + " $"; // e.g. append a dollar-sign
    }
}
```

В вашем случае `mFormat = new DecimalFormat("####");` и доллар не добавляйте

[DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)

Comment: он работает для меток, которые сбоку и снизу. А вот почему-то для значений столбцов не получается сделать

Comment: Это потому, что вы используете IAxisValueFormatter, а я вам написал про IValueFormatter

Comment: спасибо, я почему-то не обратил внимание на это)) не внимательный оказался